# SFML Tutorial not up to date?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfml

I've followed this tutorial to the letter in order to set up SFML 2.0 with Visual Studio Express 2012: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-vc.php

For some reason though I get 16 Unresolved LNK Errors. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I follow the tutorial to the letter. At the point about using Static or Dynamic libraries I didn't add for example sfml-audio-s.lib I just added sfml-audio.lib as first advised.

[image: 16 Unresolved Errors]

This is the code the tutorial use as well:

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(200,200), "SFML Works!");
    CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while(window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is this tutorial just outdated or is it just me doing something horribly wrong?

Comment: Please include a snippet of the error log as text instead of an image. Having the text assists in searching SO and you don't have to open it up in other tab or window just to see it.

Comment: sfml works fine in my vs2012 copy, are you sure the libraries get linked correctly?

Comment: @GamErix I am not sure. I am fairly new to SFML and actually changing a Projects properties like this. Never had to do that before now.

Comment: I know that pain, make sure your library paths point to the SFML 2.0 not 1.6 paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LNK2019](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/799kze2z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is a Linker Error which can mean two things:

- you didn't install the libraries correctly and/or didn't tell visual studio about these files
- you are using code which uses another version of that library

You seem to use SFML2.0 since [pollEvent()](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Window.php#a338e996585faf82e93069858e3b531b7) doesn't exist in v1.6.

Make sure you are using the right version and did configure Visual Studio correctly.

Comment: On the Download page I went for `Visual C++ 11 (2012) - 32 bits` on the download list. That would presumably be the right version for a Windows 7 64-bit machine right? (They say to take the platform you aim to compile for, not the platform you are coding on).¨

Comment: Yes, should be. Did you also match the version of your Visual Studio? If you download `Visual C++ 11 (2012)` then you have to use VS2012 too.

Comment: Won't just Visual Studio 2012 cut it? I can make C++ projects in it ._.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio 2012 already, than you should be fine so far. The tutorial says (the red box at the beginning) that there are different versions of the library for different versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: If I record a video of what I do, would you be content checking that what I do is correct..?

Comment: I am sure you'll make it on your own. Try to go through that list of things step by step. Did you create a Win32 project? Did you tell VS the correct paths to the files? If you linked the files dynamically - did you copy the .dll-files to the directory of your executable? It's a little late here already ;)

Comment: I choose Empty Project under C++ and go from there. According to the tutorial it wasn't necessary to pick Win 32 application.

Comment: It says: "The first thing to do is to choose what kind of project to create: you must select a "Win32 application"" right under "Creating and configuring a SFML project".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30445/discussion-between-vipar-and-stefan-falk)